# Lua inheritance - call method on super

Tags: inheritance, lua

I'm using cocos2d-x [lua binding] to port my cocos2d [objective-c] game and I had few classes subclassed.
For example I've got a subclass of CCScene [nevermind what it does], which has a onEnter method.
In my subclass, KCCScene I also had onEnter and there I called [super onEnter].

So I've read quite a few docs describing inheritance in Lua, but I have never seen a call to the super method.

Is it possible to do?
If it is, how should I do something like super:onEnter() ?

Thanks

Comment: In Lua you don't have a standard OO library. You can implement one using the tools Lua offers, but how it works, and what it is capable of, entirely depends on the implementation at hand. I suggest you take a look in the docs of the binding to see what API they offer.

Comment: I don't want to use any library. Just want to use the metatables etc.

Comment: You're already using a library, namely these cocos2d-x Lua bindings. I just meant to suggest looking at the OOP Lua API cocos2d offers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It really depends on the particular way on which you are doing OO. Some libs provide an "out of the box" way of doing super, others don't. I'm not familiar with Cocos2d-x, but I think it doesn't have one.

A way to achieve that is to use the superclass directly, like this:

```
function KCCScene:onEnter()
  doThis()
  CCScene.onEnter(self)
  doThat()
end
```

That should work with all libs doing OO, including Cocos2d-x. However, you lose the nice ":" syntax, and you need to include an explicit "self" parameter.